# Humidity Readings Suspect

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have a DHT11 AND a BMP20? connected to my RPi0W and located in my crawlspace. My objective is to maintain a database of Temp and Humidity readings over time and observe the impact of things like lining the "floor" with 10 mil plastic.

Here is the code I use to gather the readings:

```
#!/usr/bin/python   **Runs every ten minutes using Cron**
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import MySQLdb
import time

from Adafruit_BME280 import *

sensor = BME280(address=0x76,t_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, p_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, h_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8)

conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.204",user="jim",passwd="xxxxxxxxx",db="EnviroLogger")
c=conn.cursor()

humidity, temperaturec = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
temperaturef=((temperaturec*9.000)/5.000)+32.000
datatime=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())

dhtvalues="(null,'DHT-8200-Crawl',"+str(temperaturef)+","+str(humidity)+",null,'"+datatime+"')"


time.sleep(1)
BMPtemperaturef = ((sensor.read_temperature()*9.000)/5.000)+32.000
hectopascals = sensor.read_pressure()/100.0000
BMPhumidity = sensor.read_humidity()

bmpvalues="(null,'BMP-8200-Crawl',"+str(temperaturef)+","+str(humidity)+","+str(hectopascals)+",'"+datatime+"');"

finalSQLstring="INSERT INTO ResDataLog(ID,Location,Temperature, Humidity, Pressure, RecDate) VALUES " + dhtvalues +","+bmpvalues
c.execute (finalSQLstring)
conn.commit()
```

Problem is, I get dead consistent readings at EXACTLY 95% humidity and almost Exactly 77 degrees Fahrenheit. Here's my query

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        DATE_FORMAT(RecDate, '%k') AS INTEGER
    ) AS TOD,
    AVG(Temperature),
    AVG(humidity)
FROM
    `ResDataLog`
WHERE
    recdate >= '2018-08-27'
GROUP BY
    TOD
```

Trust me, Average is EXACTLY the same as the detail....

Now, when I moved the sensor package from inside my house to under the house, the readings did change, but only from rock solid to rock solid (59% to 95%.)

Do I have perfect humidity (my dehumidifier, ten feet away, says otherwise...) or have I made an error in coding?

Comment: `temperaturef=((temperaturec*9.000)/5.000)+32.000` why do you specify 3 decimal digits after the dot? one would suffice to make it a float? Is that a python 2.7 thing that somehow specifies the precision? just wondering

Comment: how much does the average humidity and temperature change in 1 second sleep time? how many datapoints you have got?

Comment: The temp and humidity are stored on the db as "decimal (10.4)." I had some difficulty with the insert statement using fewer digits and I didn't care, so I upped it to 4....

Comment: I have thousands of datapoints. It runs every 10 minutes, updates the database and goes away. While I used the average, the detail is just as rock solid. Very little if any variation ON BOTH SENSORS.

Comment: OK, I was forced to review my code after your comments. Part of the problem is that I'm uploading only the DHT data to the db. A pair of typo's in the code caused that. Fixing that, the BMP sensor is actually showing 58% humidity, so my problem must be only the DHT sensor data.